# Screen Scraping with .NET

Tags: .net, ocr

I have around 100K scanned images [in pdf format/tif, jpg] from which data needs to be read and then uploaded to a hard drive. I am planning to come with a small application that will help to automate the data entry work.

Is there are free screen scraping tool avaialable in the market that will help in automating the process.

What I thought initially was to read each image one by one and feed data through an application. But to see and then feed data one-by-one will definitely take some time and there are chances of human related error as well while reading the images.

All ideas / methods will be very helpful.

I need to provide some solution by start of next week.

Comment: You need [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition), not *screen scraping*. I am mentioning this as it might help you in your search attempts.

Comment: So I gather you're looking for an app then, not trying to write one.  Probably not really appropriate for stackoverflow if that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

Screen Scraping is downloading a webpage and extracting information from it.

To extract text from an image, you need to perform something called *Optical Character Recognition* or *OCR* for short.  There are many software products available that will do this for you.

Comment: Yes thanks for the information Kyle. Yes I beleive I was refering to the wrong term.

Answer (score 0):

PDF files which are created by way of scanning or faxing have image content (it is a picture of the text). If your PDFs were created through a print driver from a text based application (Word printed as a PDF, by say "Bullzip", then it would have text content that could be 'scraped'. I have had a good experience with a previous version of [PDFConverter](http://www.pdfconverter.com/resources/articles/scannedimagepdf?gclid=COLc3Nmj8qkCFYeD5Qod2nExaA), though there are other products that will do what you want.